# jBBCode optional option?

Tags: php, bbcode

I use [jBBCode](http://jbbcode.com/) for bb codes parsing.

I want to extend CodeDefinition class to write my own *asHtml* function as in example in [documentation](http://jbbcode.com/docs#definingCustomCodeDefinitions).

*Mytag* (see the code fragment) may have an option and may have not. And if there's no one, I want it to become the default value.

But I have to do **setUseOption()** to tell jBBCode whether my tag requires option or not. It can only be true or false.

If I set **true**, then `[mytag]without option[/mytag]` fails to proceed.

If I set **false**, `[mytag=value]with option[/mytag]` fails.

Is there a way to allow proceeding tags both with and without option? I.e. making option be optional.
And set the default value for it?

I haven't found this in the [documentation](http://jbbcode.com/docs#definingCustomCodeDefinitions).

Code fragment:

```
<?php

class MyTag extends JBBCode\CodeDefinition {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTagName("mytag");
        $this->setUseOption(true);
    }
 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the definitions for the default url and img bbcodes in [DefaultCodeDefinitionSet.php](https://github.com/jbowens/jBBCode/blob/master/JBBCode/DefaultCodeDefinitionSet.php). These provide optional arguments by defining the bbcode twice:

```
/* [url] link tag */
$builder = new CodeDefinitionBuilder('url', '<a href="{param}">{param}</a>');
$builder->setParseContent(false)->setBodyValidator($urlValidator);
array_push($this->definitions, $builder->build());

/* [url=http://example.com] link tag */
$builder = new CodeDefinitionBuilder('url', '<a href="{option}">{param}</a>');
$builder->setUseOption(true)->setParseContent(true)->setOptionValidator($urlValidator);
array_push($this->definitions, $builder->build());
```

The parser then takes care of matching instances of the bbcode with the appropriate definition.

Comment: Thank you! That's much better than pre-add default option before parsing as I used to. Also it'd be nice to see this in docs (i.e. about one tag can be declared twice with and without option)